# Coalgebra structure on $T(V)=k\oplus V \oplus V\otimes V \oplus V^{\otimes 3}\oplus \cdots $

Tags: coalgebras, free-product

In the wiki page:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofree_coalgebra

They discuss two coalgebra structures on $T(V)$

I dropped the tensor between $v_1\otimes \cdots\otimes  v_n$, the two coproducts:
$$\Delta(v_1\cdots v_n) = \sum_{p=0}^n v_0\cdots v_p \otimes v_{p+1}\cdots v_{n+1}$$
$$\Delta(v_1\cdots v_n) =1\otimes v_1\cdots v_n+\sum_{p=1}^{n-1} \sum_\sigma v_{\sigma(1)} \cdots v_{\sigma(p)}\otimes v_{\sigma(p+1)}\cdots v_{\sigma(n)}+v_1\cdots v_n\otimes 1$$
Where $\sigma(1)<\sigma(2)<\cdots < \sigma (p) $ and $\sigma(p+1)<\cdots < \sigma(n)$

I am trying to solve one of Kessel's book (Quantum groups) problems that says:

> Blockquote: (Chapter 3, exercise 3)
> Show that the canonical isomorphism $V^{\otimes n}\otimes V^{\otimes m} \cong V^{\otimes (n+m)}$ endow $T(V)$ with a coalgebra structure

My first thought was $\Delta x = x\otimes x$ i.e. $$\Delta (v_1\cdots v_n) = v_1\cdots v_n \otimes v_1\cdots v_n$$
And it is a co-associative
$$\Delta \otimes I \circ \Delta(x)= (x\otimes x)\otimes x=x\otimes x \otimes x=x\otimes (x \otimes x)=I \otimes \Delta \circ \Delta (x)$$
If we define $\varepsilon (x) = 0$
Then
$$(I\otimes \varepsilon )\circ \Delta x = x\otimes 0 = 0= 0\otimes x = \varepsilon \otimes I \circ \Delta (x)$$

In the book, they did not discuss how to come up with the co-algebra. All examples seem like they choose any definition that works with the co-associativity and co-unity.

Comment: Note that $x\mapsto x\otimes x$ is not a linear map, so it cannot be a coproduct.

Comment: @user8268 $(ax+b)\mapsto (ax+b)\otimes (ax+b)=a^2(x\otimes x) + b(x\otimes 1) + b(1\otimes x) + b^2\ne a(x\otimes x)+b$, 

Aha thanks!

One question remains, how to use $V^{\otimes n}\otimes V^{\otimes m} \cong V^{\otimes(n+m)}$ to come with a coproduct on $T(V)$. It should be the first definition of the co-product without the sigma right?

Comment: yes, I think you should just verify that that first definition gives you a coassociative coproduct (and find a suitable counit)